# AS3: Loading bytes from multiple sources

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am loading multiple images into a class instance and I would like to keep track of how large the complete amount of loaded data is at any given point.
I have grabbed the totalbytes from my directory of images via a PHP script... but collecting the new bytes from the ProgressEvent on each image seems tricky for some reason.
Let's assume that the totalBytes variable is correct and that I am totally unfamiliar with the way that ProgressEvent works...

*Does an event get fired every time ProgressEvent gets a new byte?

If not, how do I keep track of the current total bytes?*

I'm sure I've got it wrong, but here's what I am trying:

```
public function thumbProgress(e:ProgressEvent):void
{
    //trying to check for a new data amount, in case the progress event updates
    //insignificantly
    if(e.bytesLoaded != this.newByte)
    {
        this.newByte = this.currentLoadedBytes - e.bytesLoaded;
        this.currentLoadedBytes += this.newByte;
        this.textprog.text = this.currentLoadedBytes.toString() + "  / " + this.totalBytes.toString();
        this.newByte = e.bytesLoaded;   
    }

    if(this.currentLoadedBytes >= this.totalBytes)
    {
        this.textprog.text = "done loading.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a *flash.display.Loader* to load your images? Then you can use the *Loader.contentLoaderInfo.bytesTotal* property, which should contain the right number of bytes once the image has finished loading. The Loader.contentLoaderInfo property references the LoaderInfo instance of the loaded content, which contains a lot of data about the file, such as total size, the amount that have finished loading, and the URL from which it was loaded. Check out [the LoaderInfo reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html).

Sum the values of this property for all of your loaders, to get the total amount of loaded data, e.g. in the COMPLETE handler for each loader.

Cheers

Comment: This seems to be what I am looking for.
Funny that I had never tried to add the total onComplete before.

Thanks.

Comment: Er, actually, I don't think this will work.
I would need the INIT handler to do the work w/r/t the totalBytes property.  This number should also be available at this time right?
I would not assume that the image has to be loaded first to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this isn't exactly an answer to your question, but I suggest that you take a look at [bulk-loader](http://code.google.com/p/bulk-loader/) library. It will greatly simplify loading multiple assets. Here is a quick and dirty example of usage. We've got simple application with progressbar and we want to update progressbar as images are downloaded.

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import br.com.stimuli.loading.BulkProgressEvent;
        import br.com.stimuli.loading.BulkLoader;


        private function init():void {
            loadImages();
        }
        private function loadImages():void {

            var loader : BulkLoader = new BulkLoader("main-site");
            loader.add("http://www.travelblog.org/Wallpaper/pix/tb_turtle_diving_sipadan_malaysia.jpg", {id:"a"});
            loader.add("http://www.travelblog.org/Wallpaper/pix/tb_fiji_sunset_wallpaper.jpg", {id:"b"});   
            loader.addEventListener(BulkLoader.COMPLETE, onAllLoaded);
            loader.addEventListener(BulkLoader.PROGRESS, onAllProgress);
            loader.addEventListener(BulkLoader.ERROR, onAllError);    
            loader.start();                 

        }

        private function onAllLoaded(evt : BulkProgressEvent):void {

        } 

        private function onAllProgress(evt : BulkProgressEvent):void {

            progressBar.setProgress(evt.ratioLoaded * 100, progressBar.maximum);

        }

        private function onAllError():void {

        }

    ]]>
</mx:Script>


<mx:ProgressBar x="304" y="360" width="582" id="progressBar" mode="manual" minimum="0" maximum="100"/>
```

Comment: I really don't want to use the bulkloader lib. I find it well...  bulky. :)